# That puts us almost at the same age, actually. (Meaning in context)

Tags: meaning-in-context

An interview between a show host and a famous guitarist.

> A: Well, my guitar career has started shamefully back in 1974 when I was four years old.

> B: That puts us almost at the same age, actually.

What does the B sentence mean?

Comment: What is the source of this please, Brandon?

Comment: I don't believe that "has", unless A's English is rather poor.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQPfnltXBZ4

Answer (score 26, accepted):

He's saying that they're close in age.

The host has worked out that the guitarist was born in 1970, which must be similar to him. The "actually" is indicating surprise — perhaps he thought the guitarist was much younger or older than him.

Answer (score 7):

The fact just mentioned [that A was four years old in 1974] reveals that A and B are  were both born around 1970, which was unexpected (or at least potentially unknown, and interesting, to the audience).